# how can I get a Block hash before sending?

Tags: web3js, php, web3.php

I'm using tron-api for trx transactions. The obtained raw_data is as follows:

```
[
  "visible" => false
  "txID" => "42f813038570af414c4be51ac32e2572ec076ceae6db83960b3f0cfb97e53362"
  "raw_data" => [
    "contract" => array:1 [▶]
    "ref_block_bytes" => "1089"
    "ref_block_hash" => "eb133cb1344410de"
    "expiration" => 1684375122000
    "timestamp" => 1684375064239
  ]
  "raw_data_hex" => "0a0210892208eb133cb1344410de40d0e0d2e482315a67080112630a2d747970652e676f6f676c65617069732e636f6d2f70726f746f636f6c2e5472616e73666572436f6e747261637412320a15417b"
]
```

When I send the transaction, the block hash is "00000000030e109c85880aade973a226af185918f1e97ffef997fdee038dad18"

```
[
  "blockID" => "00000000030e109c85880aade973a226af185918f1e97ffef997fdee038dad18"
  "block_header" => [
    "raw_data" => [
      "number" => 51253404
      "txTrieRoot" => "bcbbf236aef2ac5fa7d2b31d7a3149c9b7ae7e57c95deebd2a0ed806a69ff30b"
      "witness_address" => "41c5614f3ebf88785fedf9d69bd82aac1353f8b431"
      "parentHash" => "00000000030e109bd294ea132015f2ee55d6653db912076e3e043b989024b421"
      "version" => 27
      "timestamp" => 1684375065000
    ]
    "witness_signature" => "d911e3cc11cd36cb5c52da2358a18ed6aae3f982cf67c8d743440661c6d86f330aef9314f2ed0cb45916b090d508578d38be876c85ad801ff84a651c2fdd6e7401"
  ]
  "transactions" => array:186 [▶]
]
```

How can I get the block hash before sending the transaction